# Runtime Worksheet Paste Error : Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to feed Worksheet in Runtime to Paste but get Object Required error.
I have tried playing with passing multiple types but still gives an error.
Please advise, how can I pass this country name in run time value, so code picks that up and copies the template in that worksheet.

```
Dim helpdesksheet As Worksheet
Dim hdr, cr As Integer
Dim H_lastrow As Long
Dim C_lastrow As Long
Dim cnname As String
Dim PasteStart As Range
Dim Sheet, cnsheet As Worksheet
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook

Call Import_Files

H_lastrow = Sheets("HelpDeskFile").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
C_lastrow = Sheets("Country_Lookup").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

For cr = 2 To 2

cnname = Sheets("Country_Lookup").Cells(cr, 1).Value

If sheetExists(cnname) = True Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb1.Worksheets(cnname).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wb1.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = cnname
Sheets(cnname).Select
Set PasteStart = [cnname!A1]
    With wb1.Sheets("Template").UsedRange
        .Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
    End With
Else
wb1.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = cnname
cnsheet = wb1.Worksheets(cnname)
Sheets(cnname).Select
Set PasteStart = [cnname!A1]
    With wb1.Sheets("Template").UsedRange
        .Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
    End With
End If


    'For hdr = 7 To H_lastrow

        'If helpdesksheet.Cells(hdr, 11).Value = cnname Then

       'i'll add code later 

        'End If
    'Next hdr
Next cr
```

Getting Error: Run Time 424 Object Requried

Comment: On which line? `Set PasteStart = [cnname!A1]`?

Comment: `[]` is a shorthand notation of Evaluate method and it doesn't accept variables. 

Change `Set PasteStart = [cnname!A1]` to `Set PasteStart = Sheets(cnname).Range("A1")`

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and come back.

Comment: BTW when you declare multiple variables in one line, you should explicitly specify the data type of each variable otherwise they are assumed by VBA to be of type `variant`. So that's the way to do it: `Dim hdr as integer, cr As Integer`.